# Chrome Extension.. Event handler in content.js prevent pages default action to trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have extension which is doing tricks based on user actions on the screen. I have had problems with some links. When user clicks, listener in content.js is triggered as intended, but the actual thing on the page not.

I have not used event.preventDefault() or stopPropagation() which would explain this. This is not happening with every link, so it's even more confusing to catch reason for this. My listener:

```
$.each(clickableElems,function(e,elem) {
    $(elem).off('click');
    $(elem).on('click', function (event) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
        doSomething(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think it can only happen if you put this code and jquery.js inside a `script` DOM element in the page.

Comment: Remove `$(elem).off('click');`.

Comment: I think i need $(elem).off('click') as i have to keep updating my listeners so that every dynamically created a or button is covered. I have chrome.tabs.onUpdated in background, but it doesnt help when for example some display:none changes to block via some css trick. I am not actually sure about that, but thats how someone teached me to do that once. Old off before creating new? Anyway, That is not the reason which causes this. With or without that line i am facing the same problem..

Comment: `$(elem).off('click')` removes not only your event listeners, but ALL listeners for the `click` event, according to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/). And like @wOxxOm said, if you run your code in the page's context, that code will remove the page's own listeners.

Comment: In normal case yes. But for my understanding content.js is running in isolated environment and removing my listeners won't harm the actual page.. I actually got that solved.. Problem was the target element (modal) which was so slow that it was not able to open before my function refreshed the page